# Can sockets be used to communicate in Javascript between a Windows 8 Phone and a Windows 8 PC?

Tags: javascript, sockets, windows-phone-8, windows-8, bluetooth

I've been doing quite a bit of research about sockets lately and am seeing a bunch of different stuff.

All I want to do is to use Javascript to create an in-app connection between my Lumia and my Surface, allowing my phone to send small chunks of data to the app on the Surface, and have the Surface app respond based on what it receives. I'd prefer this connection to be Bluetooth-based rather than network based.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: As a side note, why bluetooth over network? Network programming is as easy as binding to a port and communicating over it, or at least it's somewhat like that. You're not even communicating over WAN from what I see, so port forwarding is a non-problem. LAN Network programming is extremely easy if you just want to send small chunks of data.

Comment: It's because I want to be able to use it when I'm not at home. If I did just use the network, what would that look like code-wise?

Comment: Wait. Your trying to use bluetooth away from home? Bluetooth is very short ranged.

Comment: When I have both devices with me but I am not at home.

Comment: Oh... gotcha. Well, I guess bluetooth would be the way to go. Sadly, I have no experience with bluetooth.